# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, console-application

I have this console application that generates a set of fake data/information on the database for testing.

```
public List<LCS_ExchangeDataStaging> GenerateNewData(int count)
            {
                var newData = new List<LCS_ExchangeDataStaging>();
                var random = new Random();
                var branches = new LCSBranchContext().GetAllBranches();
                var schemeIds = new LCSSchemePortfolioContext().SchemePortfolios();

            var branchCount = branches.Count - 1;
            var schemeCount = schemeIds.Count - 1;

            Parallel.For(1, count + 1, i =>
            {
                int gender = random.Next(0, 1);

                var data = new LCS_ExchangeDataStaging
                {
                    AccountNumber = (3000000000 + random.Next(999999999)).ToString(),
                    AccountStatement = random.Next(),
                    Address = Faker.Address.StreetAddress(),
                    AddressOfKeyContact = Faker.Address.StreetAddress(),
                    Age = RandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70), DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18), random),
                    AmountDisbursed = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(20000000),
                    AmountOverdue = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(1000000),
                    BranchName = branches[random.Next(branchCount)].Name,
                    ClientId = $"R{(Faker.RandomNumber.Next(99999999) + 200000000).ToString()}",
                    ClientName = gender == 0 ? NameGenerator.Generate(Gender.Male) : NameGenerator.Generate(Gender.Female),
                    CompaniesMandate = "",
                    DateOfIncorporation = RandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-70), DateTime.Now, random),
                    DaysPastDue = 1,
                    DisbursmentDate = RandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3), DateTime.Now, random),
                    Email = Faker.Internet.Email(),
                    EmergencyContact = Faker.Name.FullName(),
                    EmployeeContact = Faker.Name.FullName(),
                    EmployeeContactTelePhone = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    EmployerAddress = Faker.Address.StreetAddress(),
                    EmployerName = Faker.Company.Name(),
                    EmployerTelephone = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    ExpiryDate = RandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), DateTime.Now.AddYears(7), random),
                    FeesOverdue = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    Gender = gender == 0 ? "M" : "F",
                    GuarantorAddress = Faker.Address.StreetAddress(),
                    GuarantorName = Faker.Name.FullName(),
                    GuarantorTelephone = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    Income = random.Next(50000, 1000000),
                    InsuranceCompany = Faker.Company.Name(),
                    InsuredAmount = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    InterestRate = random.Next(3, 24),
                    IntrducerAddress = Faker.Address.StreetAddress(),
                    IntrestOverdue = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    IntroducerName = Faker.Name.FullName(),
                    IntroducerTelephone = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    KeyContactPerson = Faker.Name.FullName(),
                    LastCrAmount = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(20000),
                    LastCrDate = RandomDate(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), DateTime.Now, random),
                    LienAmount = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    LoanRestructured = "No",
                    MissedPayin24MonthCount = random.Next(0, 15),
                    MonthlyInflow = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(1000000),
                    OperativeAccountNumber = $"01{random.Next(99999999)}",
                    OutstandingPrincipal = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(200000),
                    PenalChargeDue = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    PrincipalOverdue = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    ProductCategory = "",
                    ProductType = "LAA",
                    RelationshipYears = random.Next(0, 40),
                    RepaymentAmount = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(2000),
                    ReturnedChequeIn6MonthCount = random.Next(0, 3),
                    SchemeID = schemeIds[random.Next(schemeCount)].SchemeCode,
                    Telephone1 = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    Telephone2 = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    TelephoneOfKeyContact = Faker.Phone.Number(),
                    Tenor = random.Next(3, 124).ToString(),
                };

                newData.Add(data);
            });

            return newData;
        }
```

However, when the method **GenerateNewData** runs, I get this exception

**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code**

**Additional information: 'maxValue' must be greater than zero.**

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message='maxValue' must be greater than zero.
Parameter name: maxValue
  ParamName=maxValue
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Random.Next(Int32 maxValue)
       at RLCS.Tasks.Data.DataGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GenerateNewData>b__0(Int32 i) in C:\Users\Solution Architect\Documents\WORK\lcs\lcs\RLCS.Tasks\Data\DataGenerator.cs:line 50
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
  InnerException:
```

Please help with any suggestions you might have on this.
Thanks

Comment: Just as a side note `int gender = random.Next(0, 1);` will only generate zeros as the upper bound is exclusive. Is `branches.Count` or `schemeIds.Count` 0 by any chance?

Comment: I think this may cause problems: `SchemeID = schemeIds[random.Next(schemeCount)].SchemeCode`. Where do you set `schemeCount`? Error clearly says what is the issue. May be in `Faker` class, as you use `Random` object as well. Try debugging your code.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn thanks.. was due to bad data in `branchCount` and `schemeCount` which I have fixed now

Comment: This line seems problematic as well:  `var branches = new LCSBranchContext().GetAllBranches();`.  I presume that `LCSBranchContext` is an Entity Framework context class.  If so, you are not properly disposing of it.  You should create that inside a `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without running or seeing all of the code, but the problem is that one of your calls to `random.Next(Int32 maxValue)` is providing `Int32 maxValue` of 0 or less.  Which narrows it down to one of the following lines -

`BranchName = branches[random.Next(branchCount)].Name,`

`SchemeID = schemeIds[random.Next(schemeCount)].SchemeCode,`

So the important variables seem to be `branchCount` and `schemeCount`.  These are set to `Count - 1` of their respective context method results.

I suspect that either `LCSBranchContext().GetAllBranches()` or `LCSSchemePortfolioContext().SchemePortfolios()` are returning 1 or 0 results, which we can "fix" by making them return more results, but the better solution would be to use `Faker.Random.ListItem()` and the C# 6 safe navigation operator (`?`) like this -

`BranchName = Faker.Random.ListItem(branches)?.Name,`

`SchemeID = Faker.Random.ListItem(schemeIds)?.SchemeCode,`

Which will set the value to `null` if there aren't any entries in the provided list.

Comment: Thanks @gamesmad. However, **Faker.Random.ListItem(branches)?.Name,** was not recognized. The error was due to null/negative data in the `branchCount` and `schemeCount` which I have sorted now. Thanks again